# writing LESS mixin for box-shadow: none

Tags: css, less

I have a problem with writing the *box-shadow* mixin using LESS css.

The following is the Mixin for *box-shadow*

```
.boxShadow (@x, @y, @blur, @spread: 0, @alpha) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
    -moz-box-shadow:    @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
    box-shadow:     @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
}
```

but i can able pass parameters with no issues,

```
.boxShadow(0, 0, 5px, 2px, 0.2);
```

but how to call the same mixin for **box-shadow: none**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to access all the mixin arguments in one variable.

You could write your LESS mixin in this way:

```
.box-shadow(...)
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: @arguments;
    -moz-box-shadow: @arguments;
    box-shadow: @arguments;
}
```

And use it later:

`.box-shadow(0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));`

or

`.box-shadow(none);`

Comment: This is a better answer to the question. On a side note (to the question's OP), `box-shadow` property has not required browser prefixes for a long time now.

Comment: You're right but IE8 does not agree with you :) http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow

Comment: What I meant is for browsers that support `box-shadow` browser prefixes is no longer required. IE8 does not even support `box-shadow` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.boxShadow(@x, @y, @blur, @spread: 0, @alpha) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
       -moz-box-shadow: @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
            box-shadow: @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
}

.boxShadow(none) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
       -moz-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
}
```

The point is that you can define mixins with the same name but different parameters in Less. Just "override" your mixin and Less will find one with the same parameter pattern.

Answer (score -4):

```
.drop-shadow (@x: 0, @y: 1px, @blur: 2px, @spread: 0, @alpha: 0.25) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
    -moz-box-shadow:    @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
    box-shadow:     @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
}
.inner-shadow (@x: 0, @y: 1px, @blur: 2px, @spread: 0, @alpha: 0.25) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
    box-shadow:         inset @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
}
```

Comment: How does this even answer **call same mixin to get `box-shadow: none`**? I am very surprised that this has already accumulated two upvotes.

Comment: Agreed, this adds another mixin rather than using 1